# Performance of for-comprehension in scala

Tags: performance, scala, for-comprehension

I've a question about the efficiency of for-comprehensions in scala.

This following code takes around 45 sec to run when perm is a list of around 550 elements

```
perm = some list
for{
   perm <- perms.withFilter(_.size > 0)
   wordList = somefunction(perm) //expensive operation, wordlist is a list of strings
   sentenceList = somefunction1(perm) //very expensive operation, sentenceList is a list of list of strings
   word <- wordList
   sentence <- sentenceList
} yield { word::sentence}
```

When I changed the following code into the following, it ran in 3 sec with the same perm list

```
perm = some list
for{
   perm <- perms.withFilter(_.size > 0)
   word <- somefunction(perm) //expensive operation
   sentence <- somefunction1(perm) //very expensive operation
} yield { word::sentence}
```

Does the difference in the performance has something to do with lazy evaluation in Scala?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's desugar both for-comprehensions:

1.)

```
perms.withFilter(_.size > 0).flatMap { perm =>
  val wordList = somefunction(perm) //expensive operation
  val sentenceList = somefunction1(perm) //very expensive operation
  wordList.flatMap { word =>
    sentenceList.map { sentence =>
      word::sentence
    }
  }
}
```

2.)

```
perms.withFilter(_.size > 0).flatMap { perm =>
  somefunction(perm).flatMap { word =>
    somefunction1(perm).map { sentence =>
      word :: sentence
    }
  }
}
```

In the first case, both expensive functions will be executed every time. In the second case, when `somefunction(perm)` returns an empty result, `somefunction1(perm)` will never be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see your point. I have one follow up question about the de-sugaring process. Why is the first statement written as `perms.withFilter(_.size > 0).flatMap{}` and not `perms.withFilter(_.size > 0).foreach{}` ?

Comment: `foreach` returns `Unit`, so your result would be lost.

Comment: Ah, I see. So would the following for-comprehensions `for{ x<- x1, y<-y1, z<-z1} yield (x:::y:::z)` translate to `x1.flatmap {x=> y1.flatmap{ y=> z1.map{ z => x::y::z}}}` ?

Comment: Ok, I went through the scala-manual again and understood. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet, it appears you are "looping" through every item you have in your perm  with every item in your word list; In effect, a Cartesian product.

However, in your second snippet, you are only "looping" every item in perm with one "word". So i assume that would be a lot faster?

I can't seem to work out the full types of your variables, so its quite difficult to be able to fully explain.

Comment: wordlist is a list of strings, senetenceList is a list of list of strings.